# Auguring a standing pipe

Tags: plumbing, drain, washing-machine

I've been getting really poor quality washes from the washing machine. We had a flood event where some nasty carseat covers were washed that backed up the drain. After auguring from the main cleanout, the main plumbing works well.

But I suspect the connection between the standing pipe and main stack is clogged. The problem is that the augur can't make it to the main pipe. It doesn't clear the trap. It's a 180 sweep for the trap and then a 90 elbow to the straight (pitched) drain.

Is this plumbed wrong? Or is this the blockage? Should I swap the elbow for a street 90 or a double street 45 so that it can be augured in the future?

If it's not wrong why would this plumbing be code? Is the discharge from the washing a fluke? If so is there anything less invasive to clear the clog aside from a lot of chemicals?